# How do I remove a Visual Studio 2015 project from my Git repository after I remove that project from my Visual Studio solution?

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2015

I removed a project from my Visual Studio 2015 solution, then I pushed the changes to my remote Git branch, but when I look at my repository via Visual Studio Team Services, the removed project still shows up. I see that the .sln file no longer references the removed project, but the removed project displays in the Explorer tab and it appears to still exist on the branch.

How do I remove/delete the removed project from my Git repository?

Comment: You just removed the reference in the solution. Show all files and delete the actual files of the project and push that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the project folder, then commit those deletions.

There's nothing special to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the git rm command. Works just like regular bash rm command. It will remove the files/folder from the git history. Right now they must be still tracked in version history but marked as "deleted".